# Ansible get variable with dots in key

Tags: ansible

I want Ansible to read out if user namespaces in the kernel are activated (CentOS).
The respective value is visible when I run

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_cmdline }}"
```

which gives me the output:

```
 "msg": {
    "BOOT_IMAGE": "/vmlinuz-...",
    "LANG": "...",
    "crashkernel": "...",
    "namespace.unpriv_enable": "...",
    "quiet": ...,
    "rd.lvm.lv": "...",
    "rhgb": ...,
    "ro": ...,
    "root": "...",
    "user_namespace.enable": "1"
}
```

However, I had no success to directly query the subkey:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_cmdline.user_namespace.enable }}"
```

Ansible interprets the `.enable` as a further subkey:
`The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'user_namespace'`

How can I access the key `"user_namespace.enable"`?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/FiKC8BPoSbk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are special characters (dashes, dots, semilicons, ...) allowed in dictionary keys in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64982308/are-special-characters-dashes-dots-semilicons-allowed-in-dictionary-key)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To address a key with dots, use array notation with single quotes instead of dot notation, i.e.:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_cmdline['user_namespace.enable'] }}"
```

This returns the value.

cf.: [Ansible FAQ](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#ansible-allows-dot-notation-and-array-notation-for-variables-which-notation-should-i-use)