# Are special characters (dashes, dots, semilicons, ...) allowed in dictionary keys in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have an issue with a playbook, and wonder if the issue is that some key names in the dictionary I use have special character, namely, a dash in them. Ansible is not clear wether this is allowed or not.

The tasks:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: block_storage_route

- debug:
    var: block_storage_route[0].table-id
  vars:
    block_storage_route:
      - "table-id": 0
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [example.com] => {
    "block_storage_route": [
        {
            "table-id": 0
        }
    ]
}

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [example.com] => {
    "block_storage_route[0].table-id": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

As you can see I get a *"VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED"* error, although the key `table-id` is present in the `debug` of the variable `block_storage_route`.
Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Q: **"*Are special characters allowed in dictionary keys in Ansible?*"**

A: Yes. They are. In fact, there are no restrictions in YAML on the keys.  Quoting from [Mapping](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764044) (aka Python dictionary)

> *"The content of a mapping node is an unordered set of key: value node pairs, with the restriction that each of the keys is unique. YAML places no further restrictions on the nodes. In particular, keys may be arbitrary nodes, ..."*

Use [bracket notation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables) instead of the dot notation when the name of the key doesn't comply with Ansible [Creating valid variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names)

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: block_storage_route[0]['table-id']
```