# Reading an ansible variable with "(" in its name

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

Ansible var file *var.yml*:

```yaml
---
OS: test123
OStype(gb): test
disk size(gb): test
```

*main.yml*

```yaml
---
- name: read varibale-
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - include_vars: var.yml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ OStype(gb) }}"
```

Error:

> "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'OStype' is undefined\n\

Comment: the value is defined in as OStype(gb) but ansible is searching for OStype.

Comment: Syntactically, `OSType(gb)` is a function call, not an identifier. I'm not sure what the syntax for specifying an arbitrary string for an Ansible variable name.

Comment: (I would probably just use a variable name like `ostype_gb` instead.)

Comment: The end-user controls the input.. the var.yml is what converted from csv to yml.... Asking to change the input will be the last option (if ansible has some limitations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those cases where the variables name contains special characters, you can use the [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9//plugins/lookup/vars.html).

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - include_vars: vars.yml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('vars', 'OStype(gb)') }}"
```

And the file *vars.yml*:

```yaml
OS: test123
OStype(gb): test
disk size(gb): test
```

This yields:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [include_vars] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test"
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and solution... Happy learning  :)  .

Answer (score 3):

Put the included variables into a dictionary. For example

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: var.yml
        name: os_dict
    - debug:
        var: os_dict
    - debug:
        var: os_dict['disk size(gb)']
```

give

```yaml
    "os_dict": {
        "OS": "test123",
        "OStype(gb)": "test",
        "disk size(gb)": "test"
    }
}

    "os_dict['disk size(gb)']": "test"
}
```

- See [Creating valid variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names)
- There are no restrictions on YAML [mapping](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764044) keys
- See [Are dashes allowed in dictionary keys in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64982308/are-dashes-allowed-in-dict-keys-in-ansible/64983027#64983027)
- See [bracket-notation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables) vs. dot-notation